# windows iot StreamSocketListener connection error handling

Tags: c#, sockets, error-handling, iot, raspberry-pi3

I tried to listen to a port with raspberry pi and C#

```
private static StreamSocketListener listener;
```

Here is my code

```
 public static async void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            listener = new StreamSocketListener();
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(Port.ToString());
            Connected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Close();
            OnError?.Invoke(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

It runs but when network disconnected my app crashes and Exit.

How can I handle this?

Comment: What error? You need to include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Have you checked [StreamSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket)?

Comment: Yes I Checked   StreamSocket sample 

But I did not notice
In My App After Start Server And Listen To port When unplug the Lan Cable  From Raspberry Device  app Crashed And Exit and Do not Show Any Error